# How to setup socket.io server with angular-socket-io library?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

**Answers in Duplicate are not referring to angularjs library that is being used in my code because the way angular setup angular-socket-io is not similar to the answers provided in duplicate!**

Just started working on socket.io first time i have found `angular-socket-io` library to work on client side but it looks little complicated,i just want to send message from server to client using angular-socket library but its not happening any idea what is implemented wrong in below code ?

index.html

```
<script src="bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.js"></script>
```

server.js

```
 var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var server = require('http').createServer(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    io.on('connection', function(client) {
        console.log('Client connected...');
       io.emit('message', message);
    });


server.listen(3000);
```

angularSOcketFactory.js

```
angular.module('loggingApp').factory('mySocket', function (socketFactory) {
    'use strict';
    return socketFactory();
});
```

angularCtrl.js

```
 $scope.$on('socket:someEvent', function (ev, data) {
      $scope.theData = data;
    });
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors? And what does your server code look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS does not refresh view with socket.io](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088397/angularjs-does-not-refresh-view-with-socket-io)

Comment: getting error : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 1):

There's an [excellent tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/more-responsive-single-page-applications-with-angularjs-socketio-creating-the-library--cms-21738) on how to create your own socket.io provider for angular.

I've used it successfully in my AngularJS apps, I also have a [completed version](https://gist.github.com/pbaio/192b33ef80ce65513f68b40a1f748117) of the source in that gist. It is setup for Browserify but you can undo that by just getting rid of the the two `require('');` statements up top in the file.

Here's the source for the Socket.io provider, you'll just need to hook this into your Controllers. All credit belongs to [Maciej Sopylo](http://tutsplus.com/authors/maciej-sopylo) for putting the tutorial out there with this approach.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var angular = require('angular');
  var io = require('socket.io-client');

  angular
    .module('socket.io', [])
    .provider('$socket', $socketProvider);

  /* @ngInject */
  function $socketProvider() {
    var ioUrl = '';
    var ioConfig = {};

    // Private Function to assign properties to ioConfig
    function setOption(name, value, type) {
      if (typeof value !== type)
        throw new TypeError('\'' + name + '\' must be of type \'' + type + '\'');
      else
        ioConfig[name] = value;
    }

    this.$get = function $socketFactory($rootScope) {
      var socket = io(ioUrl, ioConfig);

      return {
        on: function on(event, callback) {
          socket.on(event, function() {
            var resData = arguments;

            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
              callback.apply(socket, resData);
            });
          });
        },
        off: function off(event, callback) {
          if (typeof callback === 'function')
            socket.removeListener(event, callback);
          else
            socket.removeAllListeners(event);
        },
        emit: function emit(event, data, callback) {
          if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            socket.emit(event, data, function() {
              callback.apply(socket, arguments);
            });
          }
          else
            socket.emit(event, data);
        }
      };
    };

    this.setConnectionUrl = function setConnectionUrl(url) {
      if (typeof url === 'string')
        ioUrl = url;
      else
        throw new TypeError('url must be of type string');
    };

    this.setPath = function setPath(value) {
      setOption('path', value, 'string');
    };

    this.setConnectTimeout = function setConnectTimeout(value) {
      setOption('connect timeout', value, 'number');
    };

    this.setTryMultipleTransports = function setTryMultipleTransports(value) {
      setOption('try multiple transports', value, 'boolean');
    };

    this.setReconnect = function setReconnect(value) {
      setOption('reconnect', value, 'boolean');
    };

    this.setReconnectionDelay = function setReconnectionDelay(value) {
      setOptions('reconnection delay', value, 'number');
    };

    this.setReconnectionLimit = function setReconnectionLimit(value) {
      setOptions('max reconnection attempts', value, 'number');
    };

    this.setSyncDisconnectOnUnload = function setSyncDisconnectOnUnload(value) {
      setOptions('sync disconnect on unload', value, 'boolean');
    };

    this.setAutoConnect = function setAutoConnect(value) {
      setOptions('auto connect', value, 'boolean');
    };

    this.setFlashPolicyPort = function setFlashPolicyPort(value) {
      setOptions('flash policy port', value, 'number');
    };

    this.setForceNewConnection = function setForceNewConnection(value) {
      setOptions('force new connection', value, 'boolean');
    };
  }

})();
```